# JPA/Hibernate Join Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

The goal is to retrieve all users (not messages) that have sent a message to a particular user (the current logged-in user), or have received a message from this user (even if they didn't reply yet). I've tried many queries, but to no avail. (I have the id of the logged-in user).

Do you have any ideas? I'm assuming I need to do a join on Message & RegisteredUser classes, but not sure how it'll work since the Message has the 'sender' & 'receiver' which makes the query a bit more complex.

RegisteredUser class (doesn't have a reference to Message):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class RegisteredUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
```

Message class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiverId")
    RegisteredUser receiver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "senderId")
    RegisteredUser sender;
```

I'm using jpa 2.0 and hibernate 3.5.6.

Thanks!

//EDIT -- The Solution, thanks to Andrey

```
"select distinct u from RegisteredUser u where u in (select m1.sender from Message m1 join m1.receiver r where r.id = " + user.getId() + ") or u in (select m2.receiver from Message m2 join m2.sender s where s.id = " + user.getId() + ")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct u from RegisteredUser u where 
u in (select m1.sender from Message m1 join m1.receiver r where r.id = " + user.getId() + ") or
u in (select m2.receiver from Message m2 join m2.sender s where s.id = " + user.getId() + ")"
```

Comment: What would the values of ?1 & ?2 be? Assuming the logged in user's id is retrieved by getId(), setting ?1 or/and ?2 to getId() would return the logged-in user, rather than a list of users that he communicated with, or that communicated with him.

Comment: Basically, I would need to return the sender if the receiver.id = getid() and the receiver when the sender.id = getId()

Comment: Something like this (not sure if it'll work, need to test when I'm home): select distinct u from RegisteredUser u where u in 
(select m1.sender from Message m1 join m1.receiver r where r.id = " +  getId() + ") or u in (select m2.receiver from Message m2 join m2.sender s where s.id = " + getId() + ")"

Comment: Andrey, modify your answer by putting the following query and I'll accept it: "select distinct u from RegisteredUser u where u in (select m1.sender from Message m1 join m1.receiver r where r.id = " + user.getId() + ") or u in (select m2.receiver from Message m2 join m2.sender s where s.id = " + user.getId() + ")"

Comment: I modified my answer with your comment